# Multitasking more than 2 apps?

Tags: xiaomi, multitasking

Is there any way to run more than 2 apps side by side? Preferably on a Mi Pad 4 tablet in landscape.

I'm only really looking towards a Xiaomi device since Miui allows input to both apps simultaneously when in split screen, with other devices you need to press on an app to select it and then are able to input, the window that's not selected gets suspended, if that makes any sense.